# iOS : is it possible to open previous viewController after crashing and re-launch app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to achieve this stuff below? Please give me some guidance for it. I describe my issue below.

When I tap home button and remove app from tray and while I am opening app I get the login screen. I know how to use `NSUserDefaults` well.

But my issue is that when I navigate 3rd or 4th `viewController` and I press Home Button and remove app from tray, Then whenever I open app than I want to open with last open `viewController`.

Also same when my app is Crashing and I am opening it again then I want to open app with last open `viewController` state.

So I just want to know that is that possible or not? If yes, then please guide me how to achieve this stuff.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, both cases are possible.

**On crash**, you can use UncaughtExceptionHandler to perform some code. In you app delegate, register you handler like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
//  Other didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code
```

And add your handler method to the same .m file

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    //  App crashed, save last selected tabbar index to the to the NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:tabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"LastSelectedTabbarIndex"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

**While app runs**, to keep track of last selected tab bar controller, use `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and save newly selected tabbar's index to `NSUserDefaults`. Short example:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger tabIndex = [[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

    //  I have newly selected index, now save it to the NSUserDefaults
}
```

This code will save last selected tabbar's index to the `NSUserDefaults` every time tabbar's selected index changes.

Finally, when you app starts (in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`), read last saved tabbar index from `NSUserDefaults` and set tabbar's selected index accordingly

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = lastSelectedIndexFromDefaults;
```

**Edit:**
If you also need to restore `UINavigationController`s controllers stack, its pretty difficult task. I give you just a quick overview what comes to my mind.

There are 2 cases:

- You have custom view controllers initializers and need to pass custom object to those controllers - In this case, its *almost* impossible (in some reasonable time) implement this
- You use only `-init` or `-initWithNibName...`: to initialize view controllers in navigation stack. You could enumerate controllers from the root `UINavigationController` of the tab, get their classes names using `NSStringFromClass` and save them to `NSUserDefaults`. On apps start, you would reverse procedure (initialize controllers using their names strings read from `NSUserDefaults` using something like this: `UIViewController *vc = [[NSClassFromString(@"aa") alloc] init];`).

Comment: but what about while i m in navigate Tabbarviewcontroller-->anotherVIewcontroller..?

Comment: thx for info but and your idea is good but i worried about how to manage this all my app with navigaiton+tabbar and also two type of login admin and use..? so how to manage this plus LoginScreen...and its related session and users..?

Comment: Sorry, but Im unable to help you anymore or more in detail :-/ Possible solution strongly depends on your apps architecture, I hope you understand that :-)

Comment: yup that i know that's why i asking question in SO :) anyway thx for your effort and thanks for help..

Comment: This answer looks reasonable. Look at What's App - they have this both for tab bar and navigation. Tab bar: the 5 vcs possible will save last one shown. Navigation: If you quit the app in the middle of writing a text to a contact, you will be relaunched into the same position (this is inside a navigation controller).

Comment: However, as stated above, if you have to pass arguments to those new vcs in the navigation controller, such as in prepareForSegue: , you can almost never do this (unless you have a way to both identify which arguments need storing, and to actually store them - in other words, there is no generic solution for navigation controller)

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are ok with the code part so i will just give my suggestion

on `viewDidLoad` of every view controller set a nsuserdefault value of the top most object on navigation array.

if their are not too many branches then you can manage the push at root view controller easily

Comment: thanks for reply your idea is good but i worried about how to manage this all my app with navigaiton+tabbar and also two type of login admin and use..? so how to manage this plus LoginScreen...and its related session and users..?

Comment: Woohh i think you will have to make a class(serialised) and then in it save all necessary info like account type, tab index ,viewcontroller. save it in user default as nsdata

Answer (score 2):

This is not the proper answer but you can use it for Navigating view after launching.

In AppDelegate file use below codes:---

```
#import "NewSAppDelegate.h"
#import "NewSViewController.h"

static NewSAppDelegate *globalSelf;

@implementation NewSAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[NewSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewSViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    globalSelf=self;
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);

    return YES;
}

void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    UIViewController *currentVC = globalSelf.navController.visibleViewController;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSStringFromClass(currentVC.class) forKey:@"lastVC"];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIViewController *currentVC = self.navController.visibleViewController;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSStringFromClass(currentVC.class) forKey:@"lastVC"];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

In your login viewController's init method add an observer for notification and in notification method , you can apply if conditions for viewController's name received.and push to that viewController on launching LoginView controller as:---

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(openLastVC)
                                                     name:@"appDidBecomeActive"
                                                   object:nil];

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)openLastVC
{
    NSLog(@"val ==%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastVC"]);

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastVC"] isEqualToString:@"GhachakViewController"]) {
        GhachakViewController *gvc=[[GhachakViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GhachakViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:NO];
    }
}
```

May this help you....